# Generating standalone MEX file with GNU compilers, including libraries

Tags: matlab, gcc, g++, gnu, mex

I have written and compiled a MEX function to be called from a MATLAB routine, it runs great on my computer.  However, when I try to have a different computer run my routine, it breaks with an error saying the module does not exist.  My MEX function is referencing the GSL libraries, and some others.  I want to know if it is possible to compile my MEX function so that is a standalone. When I say standalone I mean that if I just copy the MEX file to another computer, and there are no libraries or compilers installed, it will still work.

Thanks!

Comment: The other computer needs to have certain MATLAB shared libraries in order to run your compiled code.

Comment: @Ansari  When I compile my code, the GSL libraries are not automatically included in the compiled file are they?

Comment: No, they are most likely linked into your MEX file.

Answer (score 0):

Your external libraries need to be static libraries. Then there are a number of ways to do it:

- add a '-static' linker flag when running mex (gcc option).
- instead of using '-lgsl' add '/path/to/libgsl.a' (Linux)
- or simply add the object files from the libraries you use in your mex files to the mex command

The mex file itself will still only run on a compatible system (64bit vs 32bit, matching libc version).

On linux, to check whether you have compiled correctly type 'ldd mexfile.mexext'. Your external libraries should not show in the list.